# 'optional': is not a member of 'std' in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The code I am writing is throwing this error:

> 'optional': is not a member of 'std'

I understand that the file `<optional>` is located in MSVC/tools and this external dependencies section is usually populated by Intellisense, but the file appears not to be included even though I confirmed that the file does indeed exist and I have `#include <optional>`.

What is the best way to close the gap here?

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to include all the MSVC tools?

Code snippet from header:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include Examples.h

#include <optional>
#include <vector>

namespace Samples
```

Code snippet from cpp:

```cpp
#include 'Examples.h'

std::optional<Samples::Matrix> Samples::TestFunction()
```

Comment: Can you please include the code you're writing that's throwing this error?

Comment: could you try to compile: `#include <optional> int main() { std::optional<int> x; }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must have your C++ Language Standard option in Project Settings set to C++17 or later:

1. Right-Click on the project in the Solution Explorer
2. Select Properties
3. Under `Configuration Properties > General > C++ Language Standard`
4. Select `ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)` or `Preview Latest (/std:latest)`
5. Future readers: `ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)` is also an option.
6. Click `OK`
7. Save All to save the changes to the project.